# substitute for -indexPathsForRowsInRect: in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

In `UICollectionView`, I'd like to get `NSIndexPath`s in the CGRect I define.
In the case of `UITableView`, there is the method `-indexPathsForRowsInRect:`.
But is there a substitute for the method in `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Seems the closest is `indexPathForItemAtPoint:`.

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to define a range, not a point.

Comment: There is no such method.

Comment: Depending on the layout you use you may be able to calculate the index paths yourself by using `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` for the four corners of your rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You can get index paths for any given rect via the `UICollectionViewLayout` instance on every `UICollectionView`.

Calling `-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` will give you an array of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` objects, each of which will have the associated `NSIndexPath`.

Example category method:

```
@implementation UICollectionView (Example)

- (NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)attributeIndexPathsForRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *allAttribs = [self.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath *> *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribs in allAttribs) {
        [indexPaths addObject:attribs.indexPath];
    }
    return indexPaths;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

A Swift version of Will Kiefer's answer

```
myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForElements(in:myRect)!.map { $0.indexPath }
```